# Rabbi Shimon, Ben or Bar Yochai?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbi-shimon-bar-yochai

Every time I've read the name of Rabbi Shimon the son of Yochai in the Gemara, it says Rabbi Shimon BEN Yochai. But, whenever I hear someone talking about him, they say BAR Yochai. Why is that?

Comment: Ben Lakish and בר לקישא

Comment: What about "Shimon son of Yochai"?

Comment: "Bar" is Aramaic and "Ben" is Hebrew.

Comment: this should be reopened as its specifically talking about ban yohai. in all of the gamaro rashbi is never once mentioned bar yohai when being quoted as halokho. only once during common speech in shabboth 33b "lavar yohai".  he was a tanno and from israel he would never be called bar yohai and this is evident from the amount of times a law is quoted in his name or his name ever brought up ever in the talmudh.

Comment: no one prior to the 13th century quoted rashbi as bar yohai. not in boroithoth, either 2 of the talmudhim, mishnayyoth, tosaftoth. only after the zohar came out was he named bar yohai