# Ben Yochai or Bar Yochai?

Tags: lag-ba-omer, rabbi-shimon-bar-yochai

Where did the discrepancy start, and why did one version become more predominant?

It seems that the majority of communities say "Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai", why?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77204/759

Comment: As per the comments in the post @DoubleAA linked, the adoption of "bar" seems to have followed the Aramaic Zohar, as opposed to the Mishnayot and Beraitot which preferred "ben."